# Calculate duration of AIF file in Chrome (Javascript, browser-wise)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, aiff

Pulling my hair out here, because it turns out Chrome cannot load AIF files using the Web Audio API (or HTML5 Audio) and that is the only way I can find to get the duration of an audio file. Does anyone have a way to calculate duration without loading into HTML5 Audio (and without converting the file using FFmpeg wasm or another library)?